# Linking with DLL in C/C#

Tags: c, dll, linker, imp

I've been trying to link to a third-party DLL. I've tried in 3 different ways: by compiling C in Cygwin, by compiling C++ in Visual Studio and by compiling C# in Visual Studio. Everytime I compile the programs, I get the following errors:

Cygwin: undefined reference to '__imp__IEC61850_Create'

Visual S: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol '__imp__IEC61850_Create'

As you might have gathered, I am trying to call the function 'IEC61850_Create' which is found in the DLL, but it always shows up in errors with the '__imp__' prefix. As the DLL is third-party, I can't view the source. In other places I have searched, people usually talk about an accompanying .o or .lib file. In this case, the only resource I have is the .dll.

Has anyone else experienced something like this, or know how I can link to the library? I can provide sample code if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to link to the `.lib` file, because only it has the `__imp__` stubs needed for static linking.

However, what you can do is to create a `.def` file and use `lib` to convert it into a `.lib` file.

Alternatively you can create a dummy project with empty functions to create a `.dll` and a `.lib` file, link to the `.lib` file, but then use the real `.dll` with the actual program.

For more information you could read Microsoft KB Article [131313](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313).